# If I have a many to many relationship in Active Record, how do I add a new record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Do I have to create a new instance of the join table and set the values or can I say something like

student.classes.add(class) and that will work?

Sincerely,
tesmar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to create a new instance of the join table.
To add a new class you can simply use:

```
student.classes << class

student.save
```

Comment: When I do this in a rails console, the first line automatically performs the INSERT. The call to 'save' seems redundant.

Comment: In this same scenario, I am getting an error "uninitialized constant Student::Classes"